# How do I find org.eclipse.core.boot_x.y.z?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am going to study Eclipse swt / jface.

I downloaded Eclipse.

And I want to create an additional variable for the library needed for jface.

I need to find $ ECLIPSE / plugins / org.eclipse.core.boot_x.y.z.

I can find swt.jar, jface_xxxxx.jar, runtime_xxxxx.jar ... in $ ECLIPSE / plugins /.

However, there is no org.eclipse.core.boot_x.y.z in $ ECLIPSE / plugins /.

How do I find org.eclipse.core.boot_x.y.z?

Comment: org.eclipse.core.boot is obsolete and was last included in Eclipse 3.1 **14** years ago. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Oh my God ..  in my book there is an org.eclipse.core.boot. I am studying according to the contents of the book .. I think this book is too old. Thanks for your comment.